# Problem with .deb packages on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, software-center, deb

> [This bug has now been fixed upstream](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-software/commit/?h=wip/iainl/ubuntu-xenial&id=a98db57a724ea4433b03e9101964c1b594fa89e5). An update has been issued. If you still cannot install, ensure you have updated fully, and then restart your computer.

I am trying to install downloaded DEB packages. Each time, I see a warning like this:

[image]

And clicking install just loads and nothing changes.

This shows for all the packages I try and install. How can I install a package?

Comment: Why does that stop you installing it? It does contain non free  components and is from a 3rd party, it is Google Chrome, just click install, all it is saying is that this was not distributed by Ubuntu.

Comment: i would like to install it but when i click on Install it wont be installed :(

Comment: What does it say when you click install?

Comment: same here, downloaded deb packages cannot be installed, the install button doesn't do anything

Comment: @stan Both of you, open a terminal and type `sudo dpkg -i` and then drag and drop your .debs on the terminal and press enter. Did it install it? If not what was the error?

Comment: Yep, the command line works fine (see my answer below). A bug in the Software Center prevents you from instally any deb packages

Comment: Go to the link in the answer by stan and mark the bug report as "affects me" the more people do this the faster it will be fixed.

Comment: @Tim then the title needs to be more verbose, or the question expanded - the question refers to dotDEB repositories

Comment: @ThomasW. I've done the latter, this is a good general dupe target for these bug reports.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [16.04 Cannot install anything from Ubuntu Software center](http://askubuntu.com/questions/761210/16-04-cannot-install-anything-from-ubuntu-software-center)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Close the other direction.

Comment: @Tim: Makes sense. I retracted my close vote.

Comment: The bug fix has been withdrawn because the link does not work and upgrading my system does not lead to clearance of the problem. The current status of the closure is invalid.

Comment: I noticed that I had the same issue when there were dependencies that could not be met, but when that was not an issue it worked fine.

Answer (score 60):

This is bug [#1573026](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1573206). Make sure you click the "this affects me too".

> [This bug has now been fixed upstream](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1573206). Hopefully an update will be issued promptly.

What are the workarounds?

You can use the GDebi package manager, available [in the software centre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gdebi/) or with `sudo apt-get install gdebi` via the command line.

Then, to install the package, open GDebi and click File -> Open and navigate to the downloaded DEB file.

[image]

It can take a little while to add the open the package - it took around 10 seconds for me.

Then check everything is OK, and click install.

[image]

It will finish, and the program will be installed.

[image]

---

Or we can use the command line. While `apt-get` cannot install from a DEB file, all `apt-get` does is download the file and then call `dpkg`. We can do those tasks ourselves really simply.

Open a terminal and navigate to our download location with `cd`.

[image]

And run the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i FileName.deb
```

replacing FileName with the name of the file.

[image]

Finally, run this:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

[image]

This "fixes" everything - it resolves all dependencies etc.

Comment: mark the bug report as "affects me", the more people do this the faster it will be fixed

Comment: @MarkKirby Better to mark the bug report as "affects me" rather than pollute the bug report with extra information that may not be needed.

Comment: Fair enough, I am not so familiar with launchpad, comments edited. @ThomasW.

Comment: @Stan I edited your answer - there is a likelihood to break the dependencies with manual installed `.deb` files (hence run `apt-get install -f` afterwards).  Also, you assume users are on as 'root' with your non-sudo commands - added that as well.

Comment: @Stan great answer! I edited it to include images, and a little more detail. If you feel I've overdone it, please rollback.

Comment: "This bug has now been fixed upstream. Hopefully an update will be issued promptly." When will the fix be pushed as an update? It's been over 2 months since the last comment here, and still no update.

Comment: FYI the bug is still here (ubuntu 19.10)

Answer (score 12):

All `.deb` files which you manually install are considered to come from 'third party' locations where the system cannot verify the license on the software.  The Google Chrome installer as such originates from Google, a third party, and not the Ubuntu repositories - the warning message here indicates this, but since it can't verify the license terms, it also says it *may* be non-free.  Google Chrome is still OK to use.

The message you see there serves as a warning in the event that you want to make sure it's a 'valid' install or something able to be trusted, and is just a notice that the software doesn't originate from the Ubuntu repositories; it also indicates that some of the software from there *may* be non-free and may have other license restrictions on it.

It is more or less a way to let you know there may be other things to keep in mind - that the software is not Ubuntu-maintained, or may have non-free license restrictions - before you install the software from that `.deb` file.

This is not an error - it's a warning message. You can still click "Install" and install the Google Chrome browser or anything else from `.deb` files at your leisure, as it won't stop you from clicking that "Install" button. (except for if there's dependency issues - that's a different, unrelated issue)

---

If the new software center isn't working, chances are it's a bug - that message isn't related to it./

Lets go and use the manual method of installing.

In the terminal, we can manually install.  I'm assuming you saved the `.deb` to your user's `Downloads` folder.  Replace "PACKAGE" with the actual filename here.

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/PACKAGE.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

You should also run `apt-get install -f` after the `dpkg -i` just in case there's dependencies that need resolved - `apt-get` is capable of determining the dependencies issues, but `dpkg` is not.

Comment: thank you for your answer but when i click on Install it wont be installed.

Comment: same here, downloaded deb packages cannot be installed, the install button doesn't do anything

Comment: @ShahramShinshaawh I have updated my answer to indicate that the message you saw isn't related - but how to manually override it and force it to install through the CLI.  As well as how to address the dependencies issues.

Comment: This worked for me with Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: this is because a lot of repos are still using deprecated SHA1 instead of SHA256 or SHA512 checksums, this issue will persist until all the repos are updated

Answer (score 1):

For me in case of Google Chrome `apt-get install -f` correctly resolves dependencies only after `apt-get update`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable-...-amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and this solve my problem 
 1. change server repository to main 
 2. update system 
 3. restart

Comment: please add more details how to do these 3 steps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. It appeared that I've installed 32-bit version of Ubuntu by mistake but I thought that I have a 64-bit one.
So when I tried to install 64-bit .deb packages I got this problem but when I tried to install 32-bit .deb packages later they have been installed smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

Then type:

```
sudo apt install gdebi-core
```

Enter password, then try to reopen app with Ubuntu Software Center.

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
Type:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, put in your password.

If it runs with no errors, type:

```
sudo apt install gdebi-core
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. After that I was able to use the Software Center, open it and install all the OS Updates.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest which ensures that it can download any dependencies alongside. Which sometimes the gdebi GUI does not download (faced this problem myself).

Install gdebi-core by using the following command

```
sudo apt install gdebi-core
```

Then cd in the folder in which your currently your .deb package is on. For example:

```
cd ~/debs/
```

Then use this command to install your application.again with example :-

```
sudo gdebi google-chrome-table_51.0.2704.63-1_amd64.deb
```

This should download dependencies if needed and will install your app successfully.

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ....doesn't work.