# Ubuntu Software does not install pre-downloaded software 16.04

Tags: software-installation, 16.04

I have an issue with **Ubuntu Software Center**. It's not allowing me to install software that I had previously downloaded. For example, if I download Google Earth (x64), Ubuntu Software Center opens, and when I click install, it hangs and does not install the application.

That happens to me with all the softwares I have downloaded (Vivaldi, Chrome, Opera, Polarr; N1, ...). Although I have these softwares installed, because I did it under Ubuntu 15.10(x64) and then upgrade to version 16.04LTS (x64). Is there any way to fix it or using another installer?, or, How I could use Synaptic to install pre-downloaded software?. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with .deb packages on Ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760638/problem-with-deb-packages-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `gdebi` the 16.04 Software Center is actually bugged, so till a fix hits live use `gdebi`.
To install gdebi do in terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

After that start it with:

```
gksudo gdebi-gtk
```

This will after prpomting you for your password open the Gdebi-GUI version.

Now just open your .deb file by

```
File --> open
```

Then hit install package. This way you mostly wont run into dependency problems.

---

Another solution is doing it via terminal with `dpkg`(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
sudo dpkg -i <packagename>.deb
```

If you run into messages saying something about unmet dependencies do

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

this will aswell do it, but the `gdebi`solutioin is more hassle free.