# Why does google chrome not install in16.04 ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, google

In the latest version of Ubuntu LTS 16.04 google chrome will not install.  once downloaded software install opens when install is clicked it immediately fails.  It worked fine with Ubuntu 14 LTS.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/760638/problem-with-deb-packages-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 9):

This is a known bug in the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (GNOME) Software application, but you can install Google Chrome in an alternative way ... open a terminal and execute the following commands :

```
echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list  

wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -  

sudo apt-get update  

sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: It's the best solution.

Comment: I am running Gnome 3 16.04 LTS and I get the error  `E: Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can install it with gdebi package installer

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

then right click your .deb file and open with > select Gdebi package installer

Comment: helped me again :)

Answer (score -1):

This is a known bug - but this workaround has worked for me successfully so far on 16.04.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/ubuntu-16-04-deb-software-install-error

```
cd /Downloads

sudo dpkg -i awesome_new_app.deb

sudo apt-get -f install
```