# suggestions for a web browser that will search within the current page

Tags: browser

I am brand new to Ubuntu running v16.04. Please be clear and specific in your answer.

I need a web browser that will search within the current page.

Any suggestions, please?

Thank you very much.

Tom Duda

Comment: Why can't you use Ctrl+F in Chrome or FIrefox? Could you be more specific about what you want?

Comment: For example, a page that has

Comment: You ca search that in Chrome using Ctrl+F. I am using Chrome and I was able to search it.

Comment: I believe Opera has the same capability as pointed out by @DarshilChauhan

Comment: You may also open a text file with Chromium and search using Ctrl-f

Comment: I found, downloaded and installed Opera. Where is it? I enter "Opera" in dash and it brings up a Charlie Chan movie that I have. I am completely new to Ubuntu. Please help me. Thank you very much. Tom Duda

Comment: If you have a different question please [open a new question](/questions/ask). The comment sections is not a good place for little related follow-up question or extended discussion.

Answer (score 1):

How did you install the Opera browser?  Using `wget` or by downloading the .deb package from http://www.opera.com/computer/linux ?  There was a bug in Ubuntu 16.04 Software Center that was not allowing .deb packages to be installed so the workaround was opening a terminal, entering `sudo dpkg -i` and dragging the downloaded .deb file onto the terminal to install Opera. Source: [Problem with deb packages on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760638/problem-with-deb-packages-on-ubuntu-16-04).

In dash, try searching for 'browser' and see if Opera and other browsers are listed.  If not, open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade`.  Then try to install Opera again.  You may have to remove Opera first if it did indeed install with `sudo apt-get remove opera-stable`.