# How can I install programs from a 3rd party

Tags: software-installation

Whenever I try to install a program such as `skype` or `google chrome` I click install in the installation manager but nothing happens. It loads for a little while but then goes back to nothing. A red highlight says this program comes from a 3rd party and may contain non free components.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with .deb packages on Ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760638/problem-with-deb-packages-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about downloaded .deb files which you simply doubleclick to install. There is a second way to install such files.

You can install .deb files as follows

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/local/package.deb
```