# .deb packages not working

Tags: deb

I want to install Sublime Text, I downloaded the .deb but when I click install, it shows a progress bar and then comes back to install.

There's no error messages at all.

Comment: Please try to install the package using the terminal command `sudo dpkg -i /PATH/TO/SUBLIMETEXT.DEB`. You open a terminal window using CTRL+ALT+T. If it does not work, please [edit] your question and add the output of the command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with .deb packages on Ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760638/problem-with-deb-packages-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a Terminal window and type: `sudo apt-get install gdebi`. When install has finished, close the Terminal, right-click on deb file and choose 'Open with gdebi'. Wait for the installation to finish, close Gdebi and start SublimeText from the main menu. Gdebi never failed me with any native deb file. It failed me only once, but the deb file was converted from rpm, not created from sources.