# Can't install .deb packages in Ubuntu 16.04.1 or 16.10

Tags: software-installation, deb

I've downloaded a Sublime Editor .deb package, and when I open it in Software Install, I click Install, and the Install button progress bar moves to the end of the button, but nothing else happens, and Sublime Editor does not get installed.

If I click Install again, I get a new tab in the Launcher with title "Waiting to install", and nothing else happens.

This behaviour occurred in Ubuntu 16.04.1.

Upgrading to Ubuntu 16.10 does not resolve the problem.

*(I applied the update mentioned in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760638/problem-with-deb-packages-on-ubuntu-16-04))*

Help appreciated.

Comment: @muru add an answer about my OS being 32-bit and not letting 64-bit apps being installed. I'll accept it.

Comment: @Steve that's alright, you can just edit your answer to show you found the real problem.

Answer (score 5):

Open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run:

```
cd Downloads
sudo dpkg -i sublime-text*.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

Comment: I found out those .deb packages were built for AMD processors, which caused the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the answer provided by [Chai T.Rex](https://askubuntu.com/a/878518/529404).
But sometimes you just want a simple point and click procedure. You can acheive that by

```
#install gdebi package manager
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

right click on `sublime-text*.deb` and select `Open With > Gdebi Package Manager`.