# installing deb file

Tags: software-installation, deb, plex

It just shows a circle and nothings happening for 10 mins +.
What can i do to install this software?

See solution in comment below

Comment: can you stop it? If so, stop it and type `dpkg -i plexmediaserver_1.23.3.4707-ebb5fe9f3_amd64` into terminal

Comment: [Solved] just install GDebi and install via GDebi
https://askubuntu.com/questions/110059/why-wont-ubuntu-software-center-install-deb-files

Comment: please add answer. glad you got it fixed.

Comment: Cheers Nate, Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

This is usefull

```
sudo dpkg -i (package_file).deb
```